# Used file opens even when cancel clicked

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code that opens a file via a userform in VBA. So I put in a project number and then VBA opens the correct sheet. We use these files with multiple people. So the problem is when a file is already open you get a message saying that the file is already open and if you want to continue in read-only or cancel. But when I press cancel the file still gets opened in read-only. How can I fix this?

This is my code in the userform:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim path As String
    path = "J:\Planning\Projecten\"

Dim File As String
File = TextBox1.Text

Dim openfile As String
    openfile = path & File & ".xlsm"

    Workbooks.Open (openfile)

Unload Me

End Sub
```

Comment: You can try with adding optional parameters to the Workbooks.Open method. You can check here: [Workbooks.Open method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open). Maybe `IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended`?

Comment: I think that will not work because the file is not saved as a read-only file. and I don't want the file to open if it is already open by an other user.

Answer (score 0):

VBA is not really smart, so you can have to tell him what to do. 
For me you should try to know if one of the open Workbook is the one you try to open.
One way may be to check like

```
if Workbook.name != openfile then
   Workbooks.Open (openfile)
endif
```

Not sure about the syntax, it's been a long time i gave up on vba to get my stuff in VSTO.
Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this. I hope it will work well. The idea is to try to set the workbook (wb) as it would be open. If fails (is Nothing) then it opens.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim path As String
    path = "J:\Planning\Projecten\"
    Dim FileName As String
    FileName = TextBox1.Text
    Dim wb As Workbook
'Try to get the workbook
    On Error Resume Next
        Set wb = Workbooks(FileName)
    On Error Resume Next
    If wb Is Nothing Then 'It was not open, you can open now
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & FileName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the next function to preliminary check if the file is already open (the evaluation is done almost instant):

```
Function IsFileBlocked(strFileName As String) As Boolean
  On Error Resume Next
   Open strFileName For Binary Access Read Write Lock Read Write As #1
   Close #1
   IsFileBlocked = Err.Number
   Err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

And your `Sub` will become:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim path As String, File As String, openfile As String
    path = "J:\Planning\Projecten\"

  File = TextBox1.text
  openfile = path & File & ".xlsm"

  If Not IsFileBlocked(openfile) Then
     Workbooks.Open (openfile)
  Else
     MsgBox "File bloked (open by another user)...", vbInformation, "Open aborted"
     Exit Sub 'you may comment this line if you want the form to be unloaded...
  End If
 Unload Me
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It seems to work perfectly. Would it be possible to show who has the file open?

Comment: @Jelle van der Heijden: Not really... The above function checks only if the workbook can be Open for Binary acces. When it is blocked by somebody else, the process of opening return an error which is the bases for the function return boolean value... It is the fastest method to check if the workbook is blocked... And your question didn't require the user who is blocking the workbook. :) So, I would consider that it answered your question. Would be that a wrong guess?